# File not found: index.android.js in any of the project roots - React Native Navigation production packaging

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

My app runs on React Native Navigation v1.0 and react-native v0.56.0. This runs pretty well on Android simulator without any trouble.

Recently, I was planning to make a production build following the steps as described at [ReactNative page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android).

At the time of generating the release APK with `./gradlew assembleRelease` command, eventually I've thrown by the error - `File not found: index.android.js in any of the project roots`; But my project consists of index.js not index.android.js.

This is less possible to get a help at Wix Git since they gives less attention to v1.0 nowadays. So, I'm hoping for an way out here.

Here is my *MainApplication.java* contents:

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.reactnative.ivpusic.imagepicker.PickerPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
    @Override
    public boolean isDebug() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new PickerPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage()
        );
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like I able to continue after adding the following line to `/android/app/build.gradle` file at top:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]
```

The above line was not there before, and I don't know if adding only this is adequate - I moved from throwing that index.android.js error, but stuck somewhere else now; At least this looks like adding that line not throwing me the index.android.js error anymore.